# Flask-SocketIO AttributeError: 'Server' object has no attribute 'get_environ'

Tags: flask, websocket, flask-socketio

I can't seem to get to the bottom of this. I'm using older versions of Flask/socketio libraries in order to get them to work properly without connection issues to my socket.io-client.

Error message when I try to connect to the socket:
`301cd1879aca4952ab7c172036986e72: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '301cd1879aca4952ab7c172036986e72', 'upgrades': [], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}  connect handler error Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\affederation-website\backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\engineio\server.py", line 549, in _trigger_event return self.handlers[event](*args) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\affederation-website\backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 724, in _handle_eio_connect return self._handle_connect(sid, '/') ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\affederation-website\backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 627, in _handle_connect success = self._trigger_event('connect', namespace, sid, ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\affederation-website\backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 711, in _trigger_event return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\affederation-website\backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 282, in _handler return self._handle_event(handler, message, namespace, sid, ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\affederation-website\backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 790, in _handle_event environ = self.server.get_environ(sid, namespace=namespace) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'Server' object has no attribute 'get_environ'`

server.py

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="../dist", static_url_path="")
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
socketio = SocketIO(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True, cors_allowed_origins="*")
        
@socketio.on("connect")
def handle_connect():
    print("Connected")
 #   emit("connect")

@socketio.on("disconnect")
def handle_disconnect():
    print("Client has disconnected")
  #  emit("disconnect")
```

pip freeze:

```
Flask==2.3.2
Flask-Cors==4.0.0
Flask-SocketIO==5.3.4
python-engineio==3.13.2
python-socketio==4.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a fairly recent Flask-SocketIO (from 2023) library with old python-socketio and python-engineio dependencies (from 2020). Either upgrade the two dependencies to current versions, or downgrade Flask-SocketIO to something from around the same date as your dependencies.